# Issue on Jaydata Node Express CRUD server side ODATA

Tags: express, odata, sapui5, jaydata

I need to set up a OData server with Node. I managed to get Jaydata up and running with Express, defined a model, which gets loaded properly. I can display a the entries properly in a SAPUI5 table.

Essentially [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838096/odata-jaydata-odata-update-request-returns-error-404-sapui5-node) was my orientation along with [this tutorial](http://jaydata.org/blog/install-your-own-odata-server-with-nodejs-and-mongodb).

Below are the essential code passages:

```
// ...
// Model.js
//
$data.Class.define("Cases.User", $data.Entity, null, {
    Id: { type: "id", key: true, computed: true, nullable: false },
    FirstName: { type: "string", required:true},
    LastName: {type:"string", required:true}, 
    Username: {type:"string", required:true}, 
    Email: {type:"string", required:true},
    isAdmin: {type:"boolean"},
    Password:{type:"string", minLength: 8}
 }, null);

$data.EntityContext.extend("CaseDatabase", {
    Users: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Cases.User }
});

$data.Class.defineEx("Cases.Context", [$data.EntityContext,$data.ServiceBase], null, {
    User:{ type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Cases.User }
});


exports = Cases.Context;
```

Extract from `router.js`:

```
app.use("/api", $data.JayService.OData.Utils.simpleBodyReader());
app.use("/api", $data.JayService.createAdapter(Cases.Context, function (req, res) {
        return new Cases.Context({name: "mongoDB", databaseName:"cases", address:     "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 });
}));
```

As said, these links work just like charm and I am able to get the entries from the MongoDB db:
/api/$metadata and /api/User

Where I am out of luck is when I try to add any entry through the SAPUI5 client. I followed the same patterns as in above mentioned question:

Model gets properly bound to SAPUI5 table, as said displaying works.

```
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/api");
        oModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay);

        var oTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("UserList")
        oTable.setModel(oModel);

        oTable.bindRows("/User");
```

What does not work, is when I want to add a user entry. I get the data filled into the variable, but posting the data back to the service (`/api`) results always in:

> Status 405 - Method Not Allowed.

Posting to URI: `/api/User` results in status 500.

Code on Client side:

```
...
 OData.request({
               requestUri: "/api/",    
               method: "POST",
               data: user
           },
           function(insertedItem) {
               console.log(insertItem);
           },
           function(err) {
               console.log(err);
        });
...
```

Another thing I noticed is that the `xml:base` looks very strange (`localhost:3000/api`):

```
<service xml:base="http://localhost:3000undefined/">
```

containing the "undefined". However I have no idea, whether this is the root of my issue and second how to get rid of the undefined error.

Comment: Thanks, also for correcting some stuff

Comment: I solved my issue. It was an error in my attributes (FirstName vs Firstname).

Answer (score 0):

I have found and debugged the same strange uri base and it it fixed by a change in JayService.js

Change this line:

**req.fullRoute = (req.baseRoute || (schema + '://' + req.headers.host)) + app.route;**

To this content:

**req.fullRoute = (req.baseRoute || (schema + '://' + req.headers.host)) + req.baseUrl;**

And then you can actually request the generated URI and get a result ;-)